# C++ vector objects going out of scope

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, scope

I'm having trouble understanding how to properly build a vector of pointers (I'm pretty new to C++). I think the following code summarizes the problem:

**Mok.h**

```
class Mok
{
public:
    Mok(int n) : m_num{n}
    int getNum() {return m_num}
private:
    int m_num;
};
```

**Bar.h**

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();

    void setTiles();
    void printTiles();

private:
    std::vector<Mok*> m_tileSet;
};
```

**Bar.cpp**

```
void Bar::setTiles()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        m_tileSet.push_back(&Mok(i));
    }
}

void Bar::printTiles()
{
    for (const auto &mok : m_tileSet)
    {
        std::cout << mok->getNum() << " ";
    }
}
```

The idea would be to print the numbers stored in the vector, but instead I get crazy numbers (I know it doesn't make much sense for ints, the real code is more complex, this is a simplification. Imagine Mok as a big object, and the vector containing thousands of objects). Inside *setTiles()* everything seems to get stored ok (VS debugger says so), but when I get to *printTiles()*, the information is lost and I get numbers like *-858993460*.

I guess the Mok objects are going out of scope, so the references (edit: I mean addresses) start pointing nowhere? What would be the way to do this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: `m_tileSet.push_back(&Mok(i));` [should not even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1bf952a151814d2).

Comment: `Mok(i)` allocates an instance of Mok on the stack and you store it's address. Once it goes out of scope it's freed. You could try `m_tileSet.push_back(new Mok(i));` so it's allocated on the heap.

Comment: There's no need for pointers. Make it a simple `std::vector<Mok>`, and call it a day.

Comment: What references? Your code doesn't use them.

Comment: If you truly do need a vector of pointers in your real code, it looks like the vector is responsible for owning those resources, so a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` would probably be appropriate. If possible, a simple `std::vector<T>` would be more straightforward, though.

Comment: @Steeve I would consider just about any use vectors of owning raw pointers an error. At the very least, mention `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux There are certainly some uses for this kind of code...

Comment: @NathanOliver Wow, it does compile in VS2015.

Comment: @JoePerkins You need to check your warnings.  You should have a *warning C4238: nonstandard extension used: class rvalue used as lvalue*.  If you see something like that you should basically stop.  Using non standard extensions should be avoided.

Comment: @chris Uhm, thanks, I'll try that. I don't really know how it works.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't get any warnings, that's why I was so surprised. I guess VS is more permissive.

Comment: @JoePerkins On the output tab on the bottom, click the drop down that says debug an select build.  I am using MSVS 2015 and it does issue a warning.

Comment: @NathanOliver Pretty weird, it is already in build mode. MSVS Community 2015, v14.0.25123.00 Update 2.

Comment: So the output box says *Show output from: Build*?  like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtT6O.png)?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137468/discussion-between-nathanoliver-and-joeperkins).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But what if Mok is pretty big and the vector has a thousand elements? Wouldn't it be a bad idea?

Comment: But what if you included all the relevant information, like that, in the original question, to avoid wasting other people's time? Other comments above already took care of that possibility.

Comment: @JoePerkins, Storing big objects in vectors generally doesn't matter because they're moved around instead of copied. It would be worth measuring to ensure it's a problem and worth making sure the class has noexcept move operations that do little work. For example, a vector itself is moved by copying the size, capacity, and the data pointer, or an equivalent for other implementations. Very fast compared to copying each element. Of course, if big means each object has a hundred data members, then moving isn't going to help nearly as much as a lot of data accessed through a few members.

Comment: @JoePerkins `std::vector` generally stores its elements it on the heap. Only the header info lies on the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sam and Chris suggested in the comments, one way is to **avoid using a pointer**. The following code works:

**Mok.h**

```
class Mok
{
public:
    Mok(int n) : m_num{n}
    int getNum() {return m_num}
private:
    int m_num;
};
```

**Bar.h**

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();

    void setTiles();
    void printTiles();

private:
    std::vector<Mok> m_tileSet;
};
```

**Bar.cpp**

```
void Bar::setTiles()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        m_tileSet.push_back(Mok(i));
    }
}

void Bar::printTiles()
{
    for (auto &mok : m_tileSet)
    {
        std::cout << mok.getNum() << " ";
    }
}
```

**Keeping the pointer**, using *std::unique_ptr* (thanks to n.m. in the comments):

**Bar.h**

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();

    void setTiles();
    void printTiles();

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Mok>> m_tileSet;
};
```

**Bar.cpp**

```
void Bar::setTiles()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {

        m_tileSet.push_back(std::make_unique<Mok>(i)); // C++14
        //m_tileSet.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Mok>(new Mok(i))); // Previous to C++14
    }
}

void Bar::printTiles()
{
    for (auto &mok : m_tileSet)
    {
        std::cout << mok->getNum() << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your compiler support c++14? Use `push_back(std::make_unique<Mok>(i));` Otherwise, `push_back(std::unique_ptr<Mok>(new Mok(i)));`